# Trigger postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

So. I tried made a trigger for updating quality medicament( i take quality from delivery.quality and put in medicaments.quality)

```
create or replace function addedmed()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
update medicaments set medicaments.quality = delivery.quality + medicaments.quality
where medicaments.id_med = delivery.id_med_del;
end;
$$;
```

and then - i try insert data to delivery

```
insert into delivery(id_del,id_provider,date_of_get,id_worker_del,id_med_del,quality)
values (default, 3 , current_timestamp ,1 ,6 ,10);
```

and then i have a exception -

```
ЗАПРОС:  update medicaments set medicaments.quality = delivery.quality + medicaments.quality
where medicaments.id_med = delivery.id_med_del
КОНТЕКСТ:  PL/pgSQL function addedmed() line 3 at SQL statement
```

so, pls help me, because i dont know how resolve it

Comment: ''' 
create trigger addedmedtrigger
after insert
on delivery
execute procedure addedmed();
''' 
its code trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid trigger function code. If you want to refer to the row being inserted in `delivery`, then use pseudo-table `new`, not `delivery`.

```
create or replace function addedmed()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    update medicaments set quality = quality + new.quality where id_med = new.id_med_del;
    return new;
end;
$$;
```

Note that the trigger `return`s the new record. You can then actually create the trigger as follows:

```
create trigger trg_addedmed
    before insert on delivery
    for each row
    execute addedmed()
;
```

I defined a `before insert` trigger, you can change that to `after insert` if you prefer (in that case you can return `null` instead of `new`).

Comment: OHHH, thank you so much. u save my life)))0 i just switched from ms sql to postgre and this moment don't understand. So. Its working, else thank you!)